# How to assign icon/pic to custom function block in Codesys?

Tags: automation, plc, codesys

I am creating Codesys library for public with common FBs. I wonder is there a way to add icon to the function block just like timer blocks have?

[image: Function Blok with Icon]

Logically if there is icon on those blocks there should be a way to add icon to other blocks.

Comment: I too am very interested in this, trawled through all the documentation I could find but came up with nothing

Answer (score 2):

In the same directory in which the library is stored (.lib). Place your logo there, in BMP format, with the same name as the function block. It will then appear in Codesys when the FB is called